# Create custom RelativeLayout with height relevant to width

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view

Hi I'm going to create custom Relative layout which get a ratio in xml properties and it depends it height to width .... but its not working:

its get 1 ratio always or zero. thanks for noticing and helping

here is my CustomRelativeLayour.java:

```
public class CustomRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
float ratio =1;

public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomRelativeLayout);
    try {
        this.ratio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomRelativeLayout_ratio_pro,1);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
        a.recycle();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Log1","getLayout: " + e.toString());
    }
}

public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomRelativeLayout);
    try {
        this.ratio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomRelativeLayout_ratio_pro,1);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
        a.recycle();

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Log1","getLayout: " + e.toString());
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomRelativeLayout);
    try {
        this.ratio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.CustomRelativeLayout_ratio_pro,1);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
        a.recycle();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Log1","getLayout: " + e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // Set a square layout.
    int height = (int) ratio * widthMeasureSpec;
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, height);
}
```

}

and her is my attrs.xml :

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="CustomRelativeLayout">
    <attr name="ratio_pro" format="float"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: FWIW, `ConstraintLayout` allows you to constrain children taking an aspect ratio into account. Perhaps you could use that instead.

Comment: I know that .... but I want to learn this for practice ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in incorrect height calculation.
widthMeasureSpec- isn't the raw width in px, it's encrypted to contain some other values, so you can not just multiply it by another value.

```
final int layoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
faint int desiredHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ratio * layoutWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, desiredHeight);
```

read more about measureSpec [here](https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784d)

Comment: also make sure you actually need to call invalidate() and requestLayout() after getting ratio param

Comment: ok thanks I'll try